# How do I describe multiple rates of change at once?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Suppose I have a tank that has water poured into it by an infinite series of taps, each pouring at the following related increasing rates:

Tap 1 pours at a rate that increases by one drop p/s every (1*2) seconds

Tap 2 pours at a rate that increases by one drop p/s every (2*3) seconds

Tap 3 pours at a rate that increases by one drop p/s every (3*4) seconds

Tap 4 pours at a rate that increases by one drop p/s every (4*5) seconds

Tap n pours at a rate that increases by one drop p/s every (n*n+1) seconds

How do I combine these multiple rates of change to give a growth rate for the volume of water, so that I can say for any n how much water is in the tank? I'm guessing there's an easy answer for this but I have no idea what it is. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The rate of increase by the first tap is $\frac{1}{1\cdot2}$, for the second $\frac{1}{2\cdot3}$, ... Their sum is $\frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot4}+...+\frac{1}{n\cdot(n+1)}+...$. Now, $\frac{1}{n\cdot(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. Putting this in a partial sum of the series results in all terms cancelling except $\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. Letting $n\to\infty$ you get that the sum of the series is $1$.

Comment: @flan Isn't "increase" referring to the rate itself, rather than the volume? I guess in that case, it should've said that the rate increases by **one drop per second** every $n(n+1)$ seconds... (?) The phrasing is a bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cumulative rate is what you need to find. Let the individual rates for each tap be represented by $r_n(t)$. Then, the total rate is given by $R(t) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} r_n(t)$. The $n^{\text{th}}$ tap pours at a rate that increases by $1$ drop ever $n(n+1)$ seconds. This could be shown with $r_n(t) = \dfrac{t}{n(n+1)}$. This means that you could write the cumulative rate functon as:

$$R(t) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{t}{n(n+1)} = t\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \tag{1}$$

The infinite series simplifies to a convergent telescopic series by partial fractions. If you let $\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)} = \dfrac{A}{n}+\dfrac{B}{n+1}$ and solve for $A$ and $B$, you'll get $A = 1$ and $B = -1$.

This means $(1)$ can be rewritten as follows:

$$R(t) = t\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} t\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} t\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \stackrel{n \to \infty} = t \tag{2}$$

Now that $R(t) = t$, can you relate the accumulation function (how much water there is at time $t$) to the rate function $R$?

Comment: Thank you very much KM101! Can I ask: is the last equation all correct? I would have thought from your reasoning that it should be (1-1/2 + 1/2-1/3 + 1/3-1/4... + 1/n - 1/n-1)?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have no idea why I didn’t spot this earlier. The last term also needed $n+1$. I corrected it.

Comment: Great, many thanks @KM101! So let's see. Does this mean that at, for example, 42 seconds, there is 42(1 - 1/42+1) = 42(42/43) = 41.16?

Comment: Glad to have helped! You made a small mistake there: the telescopic series applies to $n$, the number of taps, not $t$. The telescopic series converges to **exactly** $1$ since there are infinitely many taps, so $R(t) = t$. If you want to find the rate, plugging in $t$ works. For the actual volume at time $t$, you need to express accumulation as an integral: $V\left(t_1\right) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{t_1} R(t) \, \mathrm dt$.

Comment: ok that's great KM101, thank you. I have asked a similar question but with an additional twist - what happens if the taps start at different times. Would be great to see what you think, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573366/calculate-rate-of-change-with-multiple-start-times?fbclid=IwAR3vYbwzDuGXeo_JbjiTJkLwm71owEXTIth_lEEzrSVhWGKMu0oQdolzzUo