# Calculate rate of change with multiple start times?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Suppose you have a growing number of taps flowing into a tank, turned on at different times.

The first is turned on at 1*2 seconds

The second is turned on at 2*3 seconds

...

The nth is turned on at n(n+1) seconds

They each start dripping at a rate of 1 drop per second, but increase at the following rates:

The first increases by 1 drop p/s every 1*2 seconds

The second increases by 1 drop p/s every 2*3 seconds

...

The nth increases by 1 drop p/s every n(n+1) seconds

What is the formula that expresses the growing rate of drips going into the tank?

How do I calculate how many drops in total come out on second 200, or whatever?

Thanks!

Comment: Figure out which taps are on; then, figure out how much each is dripping; then add up all those numbers. Why not try it for $200$, see how it goes. But what does this have to do with real-analysis, calculus, limits? It loks like school algebra to me.

Comment: it requires formulating the cumulative rate of change, but somehow modifying this for a cumulative growth in distance between start times. It's related to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567056/how-do-i-describe-multiple-rates-of-change-at-once?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: ...but if it's as easy as school algebra, why not throw up an answer?! tnks.

Comment: So; how many taps are on after $200$ seconds?

Comment: I suppose n, where n(n+1) = 200...

Comment: Sure. And what value of $n$ is that?

Comment: n^2 + n - 200 =  0, so positive n = 13.65

Comment: So if the number of taps flowing at t is n such that n*2+n = t, and the rate of drops p/s at t is t(1 - 1/(n+1)), how do these two rates combine to give an estimation at t of the rate of drops, given the number of taps?

Comment: $n=13.65$ makes no sense. The number of taps has to be a whole number. So, at $200$ seconds, there are $13$ taps going – the $14$th doesn't start until $210$ seconds. Now, the first tap has one drop at two seconds, two drops at four seconds, three drops at six seconds, ..., $100$ drops at $200$ seconds. The second tap has one drop at six seconds, two at twelve seconds, three at eighteen, ..., $33$ at $198$ and at $200$. Third tap, one at twelve, two at twenty-four, ..., $16$ at $192$ and at $200$. In general, the $k$th tap has $[200/(k(k+1))]$ at $200$ (continued)

Comment: or $[t/(k(k+1))]$ at $t$ seconds. So the total at time $t$ is $\sum_k[t/(k(k+1))]$, where the sum goes from $1$ to $n$, where $n$ is the largest integer with $n(n+1)\le t$.

Comment: Thank you very much Gerry! It's unclear to me, however, if this is a combined expression of the rate, which is what I'm looking for. We can calculate the number of taps on, and then the rate, with this method. But I'd like to just be able to graph the increase over time. Can these expressions be combined to give a curve for the rate over time?

Comment: What I gave is a formula for the rate, the total number of drops per second, as a function of the time, $t$. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Well, can the amount of drops going in the tank over time be plotted on an xy graph? Here we have three variables so I can’t so how to make that last step

Comment: No, there's only one variable, $t$. $k$ is a "dummy variable", you're summing over it, it doesn't show up in the answer. And $n$ can be expressed in terms of $t$, and you know how to do that.

Comment: Ok, I’ll stare at it for a while as you suggested before and figure it out. Thanks for your help!